# How to create a gradient background for an HTML page

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am in the process of learning HTML.

What is the best way to create a gradient background for an HTML page?

So far this is what I have as a background:

```
body style="background-color:Powderblue"
```

I know this is not a gradient.

Answer (score 7):

This cannot be done in html but it can in css (specifically css3).

You would have to add a class to the body of your page or a div within it that surrounds all of your content. You can use a [css gradient generator](http://gradients.glrzad.com/) to get the code to put in your css class.

Here is a simple example on a div: http://jsfiddle.net/8fDte/

You can do the following as well if you want it on the body. Note you have to link to the css file that will store you styles.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <LINK href="PathToCss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </HEAD>
  <BODY class="MyGradientClass">

  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

**CSS**

This code can be generated by a css gradient generator like the one linked above.

```
.MyGradientClass
{
    height:200px;
     background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(113,61,62) 25%, rgb(147,92,93) 63%, rgb(177,120,121) 82%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(113,61,62) 25%, rgb(147,92,93) 63%, rgb(177,120,121) 82%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(113,61,62) 25%, rgb(147,92,93) 63%, rgb(177,120,121) 82%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(113,61,62) 25%, rgb(147,92,93) 63%, rgb(177,120,121) 82%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(113,61,62) 25%, rgb(147,92,93) 63%, rgb(177,120,121) 82%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.25, rgb(113,61,62)),
        color-stop(0.63, rgb(147,92,93)),
        color-stop(0.82, rgb(177,120,121))
    );   
}​
```

**Edit:**

As Rory mentioned, CSS3 is not fully supported by all modern browsers. However, there are some tools such as [PIE CSS](http://css3pie.com/) to help IE to accept some CSS3 functionality.

Comment: can you show me an example of how I have to add a class to my body in order for html to recognize css3: In other words the code

Comment: you don't even have to add a class... just put it inside body in your css

Comment: That is correct you could just put it on a div inside the body. Either way will work.

Comment: Ok and what will my PathtoCss.Css Contain?

Comment: The PathToCss.css is the css file that will contain the css class you create. An example of the class is in the jsfiddle I created.

Comment: Skip the big html4 doctype! Use the html5 doctype instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to make a gradient with HTML alone. There are new features in CSS3 which allow you to create a gradient, however these are not fully supported by all browsers.

If you'd like to read some more about CSS3 gradients, read [this article](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/)

There is also a handy online tool which will create the CSS code to create a gradient of your specification, [here](http://gradients.glrzad.com/).

Comment: lol, i had the same response, same two links even! Rory is correct.

Comment: Ok. Then how come I see a lot of gradient professional website
with gradient backgrounds?
Do they use another language. So do you think it's convinient to use css3 because I am just starting or use another language?

Comment: They're most likely background images.

Comment: Lets say I make a background in photoshop. How would that work out?

Comment: As this and the other three answers have said, it isn't possible in HTML alone.

Comment: You could use a very ugly alternative if you absolutely want HTML: use an image tag and use a lot of CSS to have all your content above your image...

Answer (score 1):

Styling in external sheets is a much easier, faster and more efficient way to style your web pages especially if you have several pages that link to your style sheet(s).  This allows you to change the entire styling of all of your pages at the same time with one line of code. It is ok however if you have a single page that you have up or if you need a simple page to look different by itself, inline styling is sufficient but not common.  See below for quick example.

(inline styling for each page)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>THIS WOULD GET AGGRAVATING IF DONE ON 10 PAGES!</title>
   <style="text/css">
      body {background: blue; font-family: Arial, Georgian, Sans-serif; font-size: 19px;}
      h1 {text-align: center, font-weight: bolder;}
      p {text-indent: 20px; line-height: 25px;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

....or it would b like this

```
   <!doctype html>
      <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>THIS CHANGES SAME PARAMETERS ON 100 PAGES WITH SAME LINK INSTANTLY!</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/cssfolder/yourcssheet.css" />

</head>
<body>
</body>
```

and your "yourcssheet.css" style sheet would look like this

```
/*BEGINNING OF STYLESHEET, NO OTHER CODING NECESSARY BUT SOME MIGHT PUT @meta charset utf-8 AT THE TOP BUT IS NOT NEEDED TO FUNCTION*/

    body {background: blue; font-family: Arial, Georgian, Sans-serif; font-size: 19px;}
      h1 {text-align: center, font-weight: bolder;}
      p {text-indent: 20px; line-height: 25px;}

/*END OF STYLESHEET*/
```

Now instead of going through every style on each individual page head, you can simply change it all with a simple external sheet all linked together by the following.

Hope this helps.  jhawk2k14@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Use this http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

CSS should be applied in a separate stylesheet... never apply styling inline.

Comment: Might be important to state why it is important to have all the styling in an external style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

There are many online tools that create Gradients. Either you can use them or you can create your own

> > Simply check here: http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator

Also you can create your own by this way

**CSS**

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(color_code) 25%, rgb(color_code) precent%, rgb(color_code) percent%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(color_code) 25%, rgb(color_code) precent%, rgb(color_code) percent%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(color_code) 25%, rgb(color_code) precent%, rgb(color_code) percent%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(color_code) 25%, rgb(color_code) precent%, rgb(color_code) percent%);
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(color_code) 25%, rgb(color_code) precent%, rgb(color_code) percent%);
```

Comment: Please put the relevant information here instead of linking as the link may become invalid in time.

Comment: @jiaweizhang, the link is working properly, please check the URL and also the the information i used here is relevant, have you tried this one?